# Unable to connect with container at address /0.0.0.0:9000

Tags: docker, playframework-2.6

My `container` of `play/scala` application starts at `[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000`. But I am unable to connect to it from the browser. I am running the container on my windows machine after having build the image using `Docker for Windows`

The `Dockerfile` is

```
FROM openjdk:8
WORKDIR deploy
COPY target/universal/myapp-1.0.zip .

COPY conf/logback_dev.xml ./logback.xml
COPY conf/application_dev.conf ./application.conf
RUN unzip myapp-1.0.zip
RUN chmod +x myapp-1.0/bin/myapp
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT myapp-1.0/bin/myapp -Dplay.http.secret.key=changemeplease -Dlogger.file=/deploy/logback.xml -Dconfig.file=/deploy/application.conf
```

I am starting the container as `docker run myApp -p 9000:9000 -network="host"` and also tried `docker run myApp -p 9000:9000 -network="host"`

UPDATE

this is interesting.
If I specify image name before port then the application isn't reachable

```
docker run  myApp -p 9000:9000
```

In `docker container ps -a`, I see (no mapping of localhost:9000 to 9000)

```
C:\Users\manuc>docker container ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
4d16547cd96d        myApp   "/bin/sh -c 'myApp…"   10 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        9000/tcp, 9042/tcp   ecstatic_bell
```

but if I specify port before image name, then the application is reachable

```
docker run  -p 9000:9000 myApp
```

In `docker container ps -a`, I see mapping of localhost:9000 -> 9000

```
C:\Users\manuc>docker container ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
24b571cc0057        myApp   "/bin/sh -c 'MyApp…"   39 seconds ago      Up 38 seconds       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, 9042/tcp   silly_yalow
```

Comment: Are you giving expose port arguments to "docker run" command?

Comment: did you map port 9000 of the container to port 9000 in your host?

Comment: I am starting the container as `docker run  myApp -p 9000:9000 -network="host"` and also tried `docker run  myApp -p 9000:9000 -network="host"`

Comment: Are you sure that container is running without errors. Can you provide "docker logs" for container?

Comment: yes. the container is up as I can see from `docker container ps -a` - `9bf05ba91f3a        myApp   "/bin/sh -c ',myApp…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                  9000/tcp, 9042/tcp   frosty_bouman`

Comment: You can try `docker exec -it <container-id> bash` and `curl 0.0.0.0:9000` to see if you are receiving results inside your container. If you can access port 9000 inside container it should work.

Comment: Can you try like this: `docker run -p 9000:9000 myApp`. Host network does not work on Windows. You have to define port mapping before image name on `docker run` command.

Comment: please see update in the question. I don't understand why the order matters

Comment: @ManuChadha Check [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/). The format is `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]`. Anything after image name is passed as argument to the entrypoint.

Comment: thanks leopal. Good explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Things to do when your container is not behaving like you want:**

- Check if your application is running in your computer.
- After you run your container, check if it is healthy with `docker ps`. If it is not healthy, the problem is usually in your application.
- Ensure it is running without errors, check logs with `docker logs <container-id>`. If logs are ok, problem is usually in the container network configuration.
- Ensure you can access your application with `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`. And try to access port with `curl` or `wget`. If it is not reachable problem can be in iptables, firewall, or your application.
- If you can ensure all the steps above working as expected. The problem is in docker network configuration.

Docker network host only works in linux, not mac and windows. You can run container with `docker run -p 9000:9000 myapp`. Checkout documentation: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/#:~:text=The%20host%20networking%20driver%20only,the%20docker%20service%20create%20command.

---

General form of the `docker run` command is `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]` as you can see in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form). You need to specify port options before image name.

Comment: please see update in the question. I don't understand why the order matters

Comment: I typed `docker run` command wrong, sorry. I updated the answer, you can checkout documentation for order of the arguments.